# Fastest way to insert 100000 records into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the following script to insert 100,000 records into a table. Basically int from 500,001 to 600,000 are inserted. I am casting the integer into a string and inserting coz thats how i want it in the table (an integer in the form of string). I am using a merge to check if the record already exists or not.

```
DECLARE @first AS INT
SET @first = 500001
DECLARE @step AS INT
SET @step = 1
DECLARE @last AS INT
SET @last = 600000

BEGIN TRANSACTION
WHILE(@first <= @last)
BEGIN
MERGE dbo.Identifiers As target
USING (SELECT CAST(@first as varchar(10)) AS Identifier) AS source 
    ON (source.Identifier = target.Identifier)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Identifier) 
VALUES (source.Identifier);
SET @first += @step
END
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Its taking more than 2 minutes to load. I am doing something terribly wrong but unable to trace out where.
Note: The table has unique non-clustered index on Identifier Column.

Comment: "ts taking more than 2 minutes to load" - and why do you think that is too much? We don't know your hardware setup.

Comment: Its part of loading process in our application. I read about lightning fast insertions of millions of records and this is 100,000 records. I am assuming i am doing something wrong so want to clarify on that. i7 Processor with 8 GB Ram 64 bit OS is my system config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am wondering how much your procedural looping and the `MERGE` (instead of a simple `INSERT`) contributes to bad performance. I would opt for a strictly set-based solution like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Identifiers (Identifier)
SELECT n FROM dbo.GetNums(500001, 600000)
WHERE n NOT IN (SELECT Identifier FROM dbo.Identifiers);
```

Now, this relies on a user-defined table-valued function `dbo.GetNums` that returns a table containing all numbers between 500,001 and 600,000 in a column called `n`. How do you write that function? You need to generate a range of numbers on the fly inside it.

The following implementation is taken from the book [*"Microsoft SQL Server 2012 High-Performance T-SQL Using Window Functions"* by Itzik Ben-Gak](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/book.aspx?id=15759).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNums(@low AS BIGINT, @high AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    WITH L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (VALUES(1),(1)) AS D(c)),
         L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B), 
         L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
         L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
         L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
         L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
         Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum FROM L5)
    SELECT @low + rownum - 1 AS n
    FROM Nums
    ORDER BY rownum
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST @high - @low + 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

(Since this comes from a book on SQL Server 2012, it might not work on SQL Server 2008 out-of-the-box, but it should be possible to adapt.)

Answer (score 5):

Try this one. It uses a tally table. Reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

```
create table #temp_table(
    N int
)

declare @first as int
set @first = 500001
declare @step as int
set @step = 1
declare @last as int
set @last = 600000

with 
    e1 as(select 1 as N union all select 1),  --2 rows
    e2 as(select 1 as N from e1 as a, e1 as b), --4 rows
    e3 as(select 1 as N from e2 as a, e2 as b), --16 rows
    e4 as(select 1 as N from e3 as a, e3 as b), --256 rows
    e5 as(select 1 as N from e4 as a, e4 as b), --65,356 rows
    e6 as(select 1 as N from e5 as a, e1 as b), -- 131,072 rows
    tally as (select 500000 + (row_number() over(order by N) * @step) as N from e6) -- change 500000 with desired start
insert into #temp_table
select  cast(N as varchar(10))
from tally t
where
    N >= @first
    and N <=@last
    and not exists(
        select 1 from #temp_table where N = t.N
    )

drop table #temp_table
```

Comment: Awesome.. It just took one sec to load the entire 100,000 records!!! Thanks a ton

Comment: Though the solution worked great for the first time, this being an merge when i ran the script 2nd time it is taking more than 4 minutes (dunno how long it takes as i stopped at 4th min)

Answer (score 2):

Vinoth, Something given below could also help you.

```
Declare @tab table (id int identity(1,1),num int)
Insert  into @tab (num) Values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)

Declare @start as int
set @start = 500000 

Insert into dbo.Identifiers (Identifier) 
Select  @start + ((E.id-1)*10000) +((D.id-1)*1000) +((C.id-1)*100) + ((B.id-1) * 10) + A.id 
from    @tab A,@tab B,@tab C,@tab D,@tab E
Order by @start + ((E.id-1)*10000) +((D.id-1)*1000) +((C.id-1)*100) + ((B.id-1) * 10) + A.id
```

In my DB, `dbo.Identifiers` is a table without any index. It took only `230 ms` for the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Create index on the Identifier column and then try the above insert

Comment: so what the problen in creating index ??

Comment: What i meant was, the table was already created with index in it.

Comment: man due to absense of index on the identifier column you query go for table scan and hence get stuck so if its a regular genuion query you can go for indexing for this column

Comment: Please read the question before commenting, i have made a note that a unique non-clustered index is on the idetifier column